# Resizing browser window doesnt activate the jQuery event until refresh is done

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**What I am trying to do:**
1) When the browser window size is that of a mobile clicking a button would slide up and reveal a div and on clicking anywhere on the document should slide it back down thus hiding it.

2) When the browser window is anything more than that of a mobile browser width clicking of the same button should reveal that same div in a different manner(ex: fade in and fade out)

**Problem**
When I resize the browser to anything between 320px to 480 px and hit refresh, the sliding up works perfectly. But then when I resize the browser to more than 480px, the sliding up still happens which is not what I want.
Now if I hit refresh in that state, the event doesnt happen and also doesnt happen if I again resize it back to range of 320px to 480 px;

**HTML**

```
<div id="signup_container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Create Password">
    <button id="join" type="button">JOIN YUM YUM</button>
</div>

<div id="login_container">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <div id="forgot">Forgot Your Password?</div>
    <button id="login" type="button">SIGN INTO YUM YUM</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #signup_container, #login_container
    {
        width:50%;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
        border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
        box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        opacity:0.9;
        display:none;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
    #signup_container, #login_container
    {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
        border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
        box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        opacity:0.9;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        display:none;
    }

    #forgot
    {
        font-size:14px;
        margin-top:4%;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
var isBreakPoint = function (bp) {
    var bps = [320, 480, 768, 1024],
        w = $(window).width(),
        min, max
    for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (bps[i] === bp) {
        min = bps[i-1] || 0
        max = bps[i]
        break
      }
    }
    return w > min && w <= max
}

// Usage
// Breakpoint between 320 and 480
if (isBreakPoint(480)) { 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#signup").click(function(){
    $("#signup_container").show("slide",{direction:'down'});
  });
});

}
```

What can be done to actively respond the browser?
**NOTE** There might be some question related to it but I am not sure.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
          var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
          if(currentWidth < 320){
              //code here
          }
          else if(currentWidth > 320 && currentWidth < 480 ){
                $("#signup").click(function(){
                    $("#signup_container").show("slide",{direction:'down'});
                });
                $("#signin").click(function(){
                    $("#login_container").show("slide",{direction:'down'});
                });

          }
          else if(currentWidth > 480 && currentWidth < 768){
              //code here
          }
          else if(currentWidth > 768 && currentWidth < 1024){
              //code here
          }
          else{
              //width greater than 1024px
          }
     });
});
```

using two click function in a single group doesnt cause anything to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript appears to be checking `window.innerWidth` but are you aware that browsers these days have the [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) method for matching media queries with javascript? The matchMedia method accepts a media query string as you would write one in CSS. You could use this straight out the box with a window resize listener or you could look at something like Nick Williams great [enqirejs](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) library to get the job done.

I've put together a [simple example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lx1jhyt1/1/) using enquirejs with some of your code. I believe it does what you need it to - different behaviour at different breakpoints. I've used enquirejs on quite large scale projects and I've found it to be a solid solution to the issue you're facing.

**JS**

```
// Use enquirejs to listen for a media query match with matchMedia
enquire.register('screen and (max-width: 480px)', {

  match: function() {
    // remove any namespaced click event then create
    // a new listener to handle max-width: 480px clicky behaviour.
    jQuery('.reg-link').off('click.userReg');
    jQuery('.reg-link').on('click.userReg', function() {
      // create a context to the clicked link so we can reference it later
      var self = this;
      // check if the form is already open if not show it
      if (!jQuery(this).data('isOpen')) {
        // set the isOpen flag to true
        jQuery(this).data('isOpen', true);
        jQuery('#' + this.id + '_container').show("swing", function() {
          // after the animation has fired register an event handler on the body
          // to listen for all clicks.
          jQuery('body').on('click.closeOutside', function(event) {
            // if the event target isn't inside the 'open' container then we close
            // it by removing the style attribute, then we remove the body click
            if (!jQuery(event.target).closest('#' + self.id + '_container').length) {
              // hide open form.
              jQuery('#' + self.id + '_container').removeAttr('style');
              // unbind event and remove the data flag so subsequent clicks 
              jQuery('body').off('click.closeOutside');
              jQuery(self).data('isOpen', false);
            }
          });
        });
      }

    });
    // visual aids!
    jQuery('.reg-link').css('color', 'red');
  }

  // Use enquirejs to listen for another media query match with matchMedia
}).register('screen and (min-width: 481px)', {

  match: function() {
    // remove any namespaced click event then create
    // a new listener to handle min-width: 481px clicky behaviour.
    jQuery('.reg-link').off('click.userReg');
    jQuery('.reg-link').on('click.userReg', function() {
      // create a context to the clicked link so we can reference it later
      var self = this;
      // check if the form is already open if not show it
      if (!jQuery(this).data('isOpen')) {
        // set the isOpen flag to true
        jQuery(this).data('isOpen', true);
        jQuery('#' + this.id + '_container').fadeIn("fast", function() {
          // after the animation has fired register an event handler on the body
          // to listen for all clicks.
          jQuery('body').on('click.closeOutside', function(event) {
            // if the event target isn't inside the 'open' container then we close
            // it by removing the style attribute, then we remove the body click
            if (!jQuery(event.target).closest('#' + self.id + '_container').length) {
              // hide open form.
              jQuery('#' + self.id + '_container').removeAttr('style');
              // unbind event and remove the data flag so subsequent clicks 
              jQuery('body').off('click.closeOutside');
              jQuery(self).data('isOpen', false);
            }
          });
        });
      }

    });
    // visual aids!
    jQuery('.reg-link').css('color', 'blue');
  }

});
```

If you need to support IE9 or Opera 12.0 then you'll need to include a matchMedia polyfill such as [Paul Irish/Scott Jehl's matchMedia polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js). All this info is mentioned in the enquirejs docs.

Comment: Can you kindly explain what does that .off click portion do?

Comment: And one more thing, how to hide the particular div that is visible on tapping the anywhere except that particular div?

Comment: jQuery's off method removes an event handler - http://api.jquery.com/off/
In this case I've name spaced the click event (click.userReg) so jQuery knows which event I want to remove. Because enquire listens for breakpoints the `enquire.match` functions can fire multiple times if the user is rotating a particular device. Using `off` we can prevent a click event from being bound multiple times.

Comment: As for your second question on how to hide the visible div if clicked outside, I've updated the fiddle and commented to try to help explain what's going on. https://jsfiddle.net/Lx1jhyt1/1/

Comment: 2 problems: 1) The effects do not occur on page load, 2) Only signup is working

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the first issue: _The effects do not occur on page load_. As for your second issue the reason only signup is working for you is because the JS relies on the button id matching the containers id prefix. i.e. `signup` and `signup_container`, `login` and `login_container`.  Please refer to the JS `'#' + this.id + '_container'`. Your HTML has `signin` and `login_container`.

Comment: ok. I checked the code and I had the problem with the IDs, correcting it has sorted the second problem. But my 1st problem is that, whenever I refresh the page or first load the page at any size, the divs dont show up but when I start resizing and only bring them below 480 it works and from thereon whenever I resize it works. But again hitting refresh it doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111403/discussion-between-jwestbrook-and-ayan).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) jQuery event and then take advantage of the `innerWidth` property

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     function updateContainers(){
          var currentWidth = window.innerWidth;
          if(currentWidth < 320){
              //code here
          }
          else if(currentWidth > 320 && currentWidth <= 480 ){
              $("#signup").click(function(){
                $("#signup_container").show("slide",{direction:'down'});
            });
            $("#signin").click(function(){
                $("#login_container").show("slide",{direction:'down'});
            });
          }
          else if(currentWidth > 480 && currentWidth <= 768){
              $("#signup").click(function(){
                $("#signup_container").hide("slide",{direction:'up'});
            });
            $("#signin").click(function(){
                $("#login_container").hide("slide",{direction:'up'});
            });
          }
          else if(currentWidth > 768 && currentWidth <= 1024){
              //code here
          }
          else{
              //width greater than 1024px
          }
     }

     updateContainers();

     $(window).resize(function(){
          updateContainers();
     );
});
```

This event fires every time the browser is resized, so no need for refreshing the page

**UPDATE**

If you don't want them to be visible on screens larger thatn 480px wide you should add one more media query on your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
     #signup_container, #login_container{
         display: none;
     }
}
```

Comment: Its working but with one glitch. When I slide up the div in the mobile range and resize the browser more than 480px the div in the larger range stays shown where it should be hidden.

Comment: What div? signup_container?

Comment: And you want #signup to be hidden when the window's width is greater than 480px right?

Comment: 1) click on signup/ signin button to slide it up the respective containers when its in the range of mobile devices and hide it back down on clicking anywhere on the document except the respective containers.2) Even if anyone of them are slid up they shouldnt be visible when they are on larger screens so that I can display them in modal style.

Comment: Check my answer once again

Comment: Its already there I guess or I have to put it again in there?                               @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait)
{
    #signup_container, #login_container
    {
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        text-align:center;
        border-top: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
        box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #888888;
        opacity:0.9;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        display:none;
    }

Comment: The query I posted is different. It states: `min-width: 480px`, yours says `max-width: 480px`. You need to add the media query I posted to your file. Do not remove the previous one. Both of them are needed

Comment: I added, but still the same thing. It gets displayed.

Comment: One more thing, when I resize the browser window it slides perfectly. But when I hit refresh on that same resized window it doesnt slide up anymore unless I resize again.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I put all the logic inside the `updateContainers()` function that I invoke both on `document.ready` and on `window.resize` events

Comment: you are great, the problem of 'when I hit refresh on that same resized window it doesnt slide up anymore unless I resize again' is done away with. But its still visible if I slide it up and resize the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111227/discussion-between-ayan-and-dimlucas).